# Kafka Producer - Not able to download/refresh metadata after brokers were restarted in the cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

we have a kafka cluster with 5 nodes and 3 zookeepers and all the topics has replication factor of 3. Currently using Kafka and kafka clients (2.2.0) and Zookeeper version (5.2.1)

When couple of brokers are down, the producers are failing to send the message with the below error.

*org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic testTopic not present in metadata after 120000ms.*

Client seems to skip the metadata update by comparing the latest leader epoch
[image: Debug logs from the client:]

**Cluster config :**

```
--override num.network.threads=3 --override num.io.threads=8 --override default.replication.factor=3 --override auto.create.topics.enable=true --override delete.topic.enable=true --override socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400 --override socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400 --override socket.request.max.bytes=104857600 --override num.partitions=30 --override num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1 --override offsets.topic.replication.factor=3 --override transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3 --override transaction.state.log.min.isr=1 --override log.retention.hours=48 --override log.segment.bytes=1073741824 --override log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000 --override zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000 --override confluent.support.metrics.enable=true --override group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0 --override confluent.support.customer.id=anonymous
```

**Producer config:**

```
acks = 1
    batch.size = 8192
    bootstrap.servers = []
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = C02Z93MPLVCH
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 120000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 20000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 20000
    request.timeout.ms = 300000
    retries = 2
    retry.backoff.ms = 500
```

Did anyone faced the same issue? - we normally expect kafka clients to download the metadata incase the brokers are down after some retries.We would have to restart the server to initialize the connections again after waiting for couple of hours.

Is this the expected behaviour?